# Sanitize input in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I send something like

```
{
    "description": "Hello World <script>alert('hacked');</script>"
}
```

to my django rest framework view, I want to get rid of the the script tags.

1. Is there a convenient way to do this, that does not involve overwriting all the things and add `strip_tags`?
2. What else is to do to sanitize input?
3. Did I really overread that section in the drf docs or isn't that covered?

Comment: I think you might be hitting [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/159034) here. While you should always worry about sanitation, you should also be escaping any HTML before it is displayed (using `textContent` in JS, for example) instead of relying on it being sanitized ahead of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ignore the answers here, they are terrible.

Use [bleach](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach). You won't get every edge case. This is *the* situation to use a library in. Your client has control of the client side by definition.

Comment: But the concept is still valid, right? I should use bleach.clean in any of the places CuriousGeorge mentioned, right? Honestly, it'd be great to have a Bleach mixin for Serializers. Maybe even bleach by default... ^^

Comment: The bleach library is [deprecated](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach/issues/698) now, a good alternative seems to be [nh3](https://github.com/messense/nh3).

Answer (score -3):

You can override the view's [perform_create](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) method  and with a bit of regular expression do something like so

```
import re
class MyView(generics.CreateAPIView):
      ......
      ......
      def perform_create(self, serializer):
            replacement=re.sub('</*script>','',serializer.validated_data.get('description'))
            serializer.save(description=replacement)
```

This is assuming you are using CreateAPIView or one of its mixins.
Or you could create a [custom](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) serializer field,

```
class MyCustomField(serializers.CharField):


    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data=re.sub('</*script>','',data)
        return super(MyCustomField,self).to_internal_value(data)
```

and

```
class MySerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
      description=MyCustomField()
      class Meta:
           model= MyModel
```

Comment: I'm using various implementations. If i'd do something like that, wouldn't serializers be the place to put it?

Comment: Ok. You probably have to define your own serializer field using custom fields.

Comment: Perhaps as Kevin Brown suggested sanitation should be done on the client side (if you have control over your API clients).

Comment: This is not generic nor safe. There are many other ways to execute an XSS attack.